# How to remove code-repetition in identical activities of different apps?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, code-reuse

I have coded for an app **X**. Now, I've to make a couple more apps and these new apps will have almost half of the activities exactly identical to **X**.

The easily-done bad way would be just to pick the recurring code from **X** and paste it to all the newer apps. But I want a good way. So that if in the future I decide to change one of the common activities, the change should reflect in all the apps where the identical activity has been used.

Should I create a library of **X**, and import it? What's the recommended way to implement this partial re-usability feature of activities?

Comment: Would it be acceptable for your new app to require that app X be installed?  Apps can launch activities from other apps.

Comment: no. The user may or may not have the app X installed in his phone. I want to keep all the apps independent of each other in terms of UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is a broad answer.

You can create a library!

In the library, you would want to add all the activities that are shared across all the apps. Let's call them `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` and `ActivityC`.

In each of the apps, including X, you use gradle to link the library with the app. And then you can start all those activities.

You may also want to add some kind of public interface to `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` and `ActivityC`, depending on your requirements. If `ActivityA` in app X has a button that's green but `ActivityA` in app Y has a yellow button. You might want to expose the methods like `setButtonColor`.

If you want to make changes to the shared activities, just change it in the library. Then, update the library to the newest version in your apps.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll try that. Thanks for the response.